# Data is fetched and stored into redux but when accessing it comes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am making api call in my redux action creator storing those data into my redux state, but when trying to access that using useSelector getting undefined.
Not able to understand where i am doing wrong. Any help here would be great. I am using redux toolkit.
Attaching snipped for reducers, action creator, component, redux state snapshot from redux dev tools and debugging logs

Note: appID will come from path params but for now i am hardcoding it
In my SuggestedAudience snipped if i comment out {app.name} which is causing the problem then my redux states are loaded correctly, snapshot attached [image]

Observation: If i am making any changes to Suggested audience and saving then i am getting value but when reloading it 2-3 times again the error comes.

```js
//apps slice to store apps
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import _ from "lodash";

const appsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "apps",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    appSuccess(state, action) {
      const apps = _.keyBy(action.payload.data, "uuid");
      return apps;
    },
  },
});

export const appsAction = appsSlice.actions;
export default appsSlice.reducer;
```

```js
//ui-slice to store app data
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const uiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: { appId: null, orgId: null },
  reducers: {
    setAppId(state, action) {
      state.appId = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const uiAction = uiSlice.actions;
export default uiSlice.reducer;
```

```js
//App.js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import PageHeader from "./components/PageHeader";
import SuggestedAudiences from "./components/SuggestedAudiences";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { uiAction } from "./components/store/ui-slice";
import { appsAction } from "./components/store/apps-slice";
import { fetchApps } from "./components/store/apps-action";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const appID = "52f14657d6c765401a2d7d4-41dfb38a-4262-11e3-9166-005cf8cbabd8";

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(uiAction.setAppId(appID));
    dispatch(fetchApps());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader />
      <SuggestedAudiences />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
//Suggested Audiences
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { fetchApps } from "./store/apps-action";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { uiAction } from "./store/ui-slice";

const SuggestedAudiences = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const appId = useSelector((state) => state.ui.appId);
  const app = useSelector((state) => state.apps[appId]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Suggested Audiences </div>
      {app.name}
    </>
  );
};

export default SuggestedAudiences;
```

[image: this is the error i get in console, because it can not read the app.name]

Comment: Observation: If i am making any changes to Suggested audience and saving then i am getting value but when reloading it 2-3 times again the error comes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this  line

```js
const app = useSelector((state) => state.apps[appId]);
```

into this

```js
const app = useSelector((state) => state?.apps[appId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing {app && app.name} or {app?.name} would also work.
Keeping it open if someone can help me understand it why it is happening and is there any other way to fix this so that undefined doesn't come in first place itself.